# Android Studio sometimes doesn't see modules changes (maybe not only modules...)

Tags: android-studio

I make changes inside my android libraries -> build project -> very often I see a new apk builded with old changes.
I have 'Instant Run' disabled .
**It's quite annoying problem!!!**
Clean helps ...

**Windows AS 2.1.2**

SEEMS LIKE THERE ARE PROBLEMS WITH CACHE!!!

And in this case Debugger also doesn't work, because it doesn't see new changes and just skips them.

Please fix these problems! I have to clean every time project to make sure that I run a fresh apk.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem was due to:

```
  applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                def file = output.outputFile
                output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you have problem related to the SDK cache.
**Try the next step to "Refresh" your IDE (android studio)**

1. Try [Choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Comment: Just tried, looking forward to test and let you know.
In any case many thanks.